# How to look at a transform in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my object to point to the player 2d unity, I have tried this code but it seems to give inaccurate results

```cs
Vector3 playerPos = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform.position; 
Vector2  enemyDirection = (playerPos - transform.position);
float angle = Mathf.Atan2( enemyDirection.y, enemyDirection.x ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
     
transform.Rotate( 0f,0f, angle);
```

Answer (score 0):

From where your game is 2D, it looks like the axis is facing the right side. Therefore, the following code solves the problem.

```cs
Vector2  enemyDirection = (playerPos - transform.position);
transform.right = enemyDirection.normalized;
```

Comment: i could not really understand you, can you explain more?

Comment: @Mohammad_io_ In Unity, you can set the direction of the object directly. It is enough to assign the transform direction to the normalize vector.